# How to set the scrolltop() method to the sliding div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sliding div, or we can say that its a on click expand and collapse div(toggle).
I want to apply the .scrollTop() to the div. when the button is clicked to expand the div
    before expand  set to top, and then expand. I tried it more then hundreds times
    with different ways but i unable to get the desired result. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="mainarea">
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
</div>
<div  class="show_hide">
<p> Click me</p>
</div>



var currentscrollpos;
currentscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:100}, 'slow')
    return false;
  });


});
$(document).click(function()
{
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: currentscrollpos }, 0);
});



//This is my css

#mainarea{width:550px; height:300px;background-color: yellow;}

.slidingDiv {
height:200px;
background-color: white;
margin-top:10px;
width:261px;
background-color: black;

}

.show_hide {
display:none;
}
#notificationFooter {
background:#FFFFFF; margin:0 auto; height:8px; width:96px;
 }
This is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/muheetmehfooz/wmwn5424/
```

Comment: fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/muheetmehfooz/wmwn5424/

Comment: Please put it as an answer.:)

Comment: Nadeem what you mean i didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not bring you to top, just move you bit up. However, if your question is only about how to make this actions in right order - try this.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/wmwn5424/1/)

```
just use callback function
```

P.S.
 to get to the top use

```
{scrollTop:currentscrollpos}
```